# parameter causes the data unreadable in the form 2 does not appear on the web version of vb.net

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim id As String, sLogon_User As String, sAuth_User As String, sUser_ID As String
    Dim sServer_Name As String
    Dim sIP_Address As String
    sIP_Address = Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")


    Dim hit As New PagePosting
    Dim currentPosting As Posting = CmsHttpContext.Current.Posting

    Dim webContext As WebAuthorContext
    webContext = WebAuthorContext.Current

    'sNama_Perusahaan = Request.QueryString("sentraID")
    'Response.Write("masuk sini dgn nilai = " & CmsHttpContext.Current.CmsQueryString())
    sData = ""
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then


        'sNama_Perusahaan = Request.ServerVariables("sentraID")
        sNama_Perusahaan = Request.QueryString("sentraID")
        '  sNama_Perusahaan = Request.QueryString("sentraID")
        Response.Write("masuk sini dgn nilai = " & Request.QueryString("sentraID") & sNama_Perusahaan)
        tampil(sNama_Perusahaan)


    End If



Sub tampil(ByVal sParam As String)

    Dim rd As SqlDataReader
    Dim myConnection = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("RegBIK"))
    myConnection.Open()

    Dim adadata As Integer

    '   Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand("select count (*)  from kuesioner where ltrim(rtrim(NmPerush)) ='aaa'", myConnection)
    Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand("select count (*)  from kuesioner where ltrim(rtrim(NmPerush)) ='&sParam'", myConnection)

    rd = myCommand.ExecuteReader
    While rd.Read
        adadata = rd.GetInt32(0)
    End While


    myConnection.close()

    Try
        If adadata > 0 Then
            myConnection.Open()
            ' Dim myCommands As New SqlCommand("select * from kuesioner where ltrim(rtrim(NmPerush)) ='aaa'", myConnection)
            Dim myCommands As New SqlCommand("select * from kuesioner where ltrim(rtrim(NmPerush)) ='&sParam'", myConnection)

            rd = myCommands.ExecuteReader
            While rd.Read
                disabledAll()
                Me.btnUpload.Enabled = False
                Me.btnPreview.Enabled = True
                txtNmPerush.Value = rd.GetString(1)
                Me.txtNmPemilik.Value = rd.GetString(2)
                Me.txtAlmtPerush.Value = rd.GetString(3)
                Me.txttlpn.Value = rd.GetString(4)
                Me.txtEmail.Value = rd.GetString(5)
                Me.txtLamaPerush.Value = rd.GetString(6)
                Me.txtJenis.Value = rd.GetString(7)
                Me.txtSpesialisasi.Value = rd.GetString(8)
                Me.txtkualitas.Value = rd.GetString(9)
                Me.txtMerk.Value = rd.GetString(10)
                Me.txtStandarPesanan.Value = rd.GetString(11)
                Me.txtProduksi.Value = rd.GetString(12)
                Me.txtlokal.Value = rd.GetString(13)
                Me.txtnasional.Value = rd.GetString(14)
                Me.txtekspor.Value = rd.GetString(15)
                Me.txtpengalaman.Value = rd.GetString(16)
                Me.txtlamaekspor.Value = rd.GetString(17)
                Me.txtbiaya.Value = rd.GetString(18)

            End While
        Else
            clearAll()

        End If
        rd.Close()
        myConnection.close()

    Catch SQLexc As SqlException

        Response.Write("Open Failed. Error Details are: " & SQLexc.ToString())
    End Try



End Sub
```

the source code to get the first parameter, the second to throw codingan parameters to form 2 and the third codingan to read in the form 2..I've tried but still can not

Answer (score 0):

I would think that that code would produce an error, but you did not state that.

To add a parameter to the SQL statement:

```
Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM kuesioner WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(NmPerush)) = @param1", myConnection)

myCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "param1", _
                                                .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, _
                                                .Size = 200, _
                                                .Value = sParam})
```

Please alter the .SqlDbType and .Size to match the definition in the database.

Comment: @yuliana Please state exactly what the problem is. Did you change your code in both places where you use the SQL query? What result did you expect, and what result did it return? If you are not confident writing in English, you could ask a friend to help, or use Google translate: https://translate.google.com/